# Extract Double Value from String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, double

I am using **location** to access the current temperature in my app. I got the *weather* temperature but I need only **double** value from it.

```
let weatherTemp = "41.7°C"
```

The required thing is:

> weatherTemp = 41.7

How can I do that? I used:

```
extension Double {
    static func parse(from string: String) -> Double? {
        return Double(string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined())
    }
}
```

This prints all the digits but not the decimal. I need the decimal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string on the '°' and convert the first part to Double

```
if let tempString = weatherTemp.split(separator: "°").first, let temp = Double(tempString) {
    print(temp)
}
```